# Where can I look to investigate and learn about broader classes of symmetries for algebraic structures?

Tags: functional-analysis, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, systems-of-equations, symmetry

Here's $f(x) = x^2,$ it has the property that $f(-x) = f(x).$

I have a couple questions related to this topic:

1.) Is there a broader name for symmetries of the form $f(h(x)) = f(x)$ for invertible $h$?

2.) Is there a broader name of symmetries that keep a manifold invariant, for the cases that a manifold is defined by a system of equations like $x^2 + y = z$, $z^2 - 1 = y^2$ and so on?

3.) How do we keep the "symmetry" invariant of the specific coordinates? Every parabola has a line of symmetry about its vertex, but in the example I provided, the line of symmetry is stuck at the line $x = 0,$ how do we classify and find symmetries that are irregardless of the specific coordinates, to say that a parabola has a symmetry about *some* line centered at its vertex?

4.) How do we know we've found *all* symmetries of a given manifold, at least in 2D or 3D cases?

Answer (score 1):

1. In this generality they're just called "symmetries." You'll have to get more specific to get a specific answer to this.
2. It depends. Continuous symmetries are called [homeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism). Smooth symmetries are called [diffeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism). Generally, symmetries in some [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) are called [automorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism).
3. It depends. Generally we try to find a description of the object we're interested in that doesn't depend on a choice of coordinates. In general it's a hard question to find all symmetries of some object.
4. Again, in general it's a hard question to find all symmetries of some object. You know this the same way you know anything else in mathematics: by proving it. If you ask about a more specific example then more specific things can be said.

Comment: Okay, let's take one question one at a time then. I'm interested in symmetries of the form $f(h(x)) = f(x),$ the generalization of $f(-x) = f(x).$ What branch of math most closely studies this? $f(-x) = f(x)$ is an example of a discrete symmetry, but could it be a holomorphic symmetry if you interpolate over complex numbers?

Comment: @askquestions4: yes, one could ask for continuous families of symmetries, or smooth or even holomorphic. This is still a very general question so many branches of math are relevant, as I mentioned in my answer to your other question: group theory, Lie theory, representation theory, harmonic analysis... it would help if you got even more specific than this, e.g. naming a specific function $f$ and a specific class of symmetries $h$ you want to characterize (algebraic, continuous, smooth, holomorphic, etc.).

Comment: But what I'm interested in is as general as I presented it. I guess we could be more specific to start with $f$ and $h$ being analytic. Given $f$, what is the name or process by which we find symmetries such that $f(h(x)) = f(x)$?

Comment: @askquestions4: it's just called "finding the symmetries," I guess. Again, you are asking an extremely general question. I am going to specifically limit attention to the function $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity. A basic observation is that any function $h$ satisfying $f(h(x)) = f(x)$ must permute the level sets $f^{-1}(r) = \{ \pm \sqrt{r} \}$. Equivalently, for any particular $x$ we must have $h(x) = x$ or $h(x) = -x$. It follows that if $h$ is continuous and invertible then the only possibilities are $h(x) = x$ for all $x$ or $h(x) = -x$ for all $x$.

Comment: This example was pretty easy to deal with because the level sets were so small. If $f$ had been a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ then its level sets would be manifolds (or more complicated objects) and things would get more complicated.